# how to get a value of elements of a row of table when radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a JSP page in which i am dynamically creating a table based on the query from database.I have a radio button as my first column for each row. I want that on click of particular radio button, all the elements value in that row is passed to a button.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `click` handler to the radio button, probably using a delegated handler rooted on the table. In the handler, `this` will refer to the button, and so you can access its parent (or ancestor) row. E.g.:

```
$("selector-for-the-table").on("click", "input[type=radio]", function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    // ...
});
```

If you want to get information from the other elements in that same row, you can use [`row.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) to find them within the row.

See *Direct and Delegated Events* in [the `on` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more about delegated handlers, and various other parts of the `on` documentation for how `this` is determined, etc.

Example:

```js
$("#the-table").on("click", "input[type=radio]", function() {
  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  alert(row.find("input").not(this).map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join(", "));
});
var counter = 0;
addRow();
function addRow() {
  $("#the-table tbody").append(
    "<tr>" +
      "<td><input type=radio></td>" +
      "<td><input type=text value=" + counter + "></td>" +
      "<td><input type=text value=" + (counter * 10) + "></td>" +
    "</tr>"
  );
  if (++counter < 10) {
    setTimeout(addRow, 500);
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="the-table">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want one button also,on click of that button value of that row should be shown.

Comment: Yes one more thing here we are able to select multiple radio button ,it is not getting disabled on click of other radio button.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, could you please tell me how to access single column in the row by name/id and assign its value to an input text box residing towards end of the form?

Comment: @CodeForGood - I'd need an example. I suggest posting a question (after all the usual things -- research, experimentation, etc.) :-)