# How to get the value of entire dynamic row in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table that is being populated by a given sql query, that has a radio button at the end.
How can i get the entire row value of a selected radio button passed to a different page?

```
results=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlitem);
while ($dat=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){

 echo "<tr>";

 echo "<td>".$dat['sellername']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$dat['itemname']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$dat['maker']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$dat['details']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$dat['condition']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$dat['price']."</td>";
 echo "<td> <input type='radio' name='selc' width ='5px'> </td>"; 

echo "</tr>";
}
```

I have tried various combinations but for some reason the entire row value doesn't come. The last and closest option that I tried was this [SOMETHING CLOSELY SIMILAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166361/how-to-get-a-value-of-elements-of-a-row-of-table-when-radio-button-is-selected)

I took the script portion and updated still isn't working. I believe there should be some solution for this.

Comment: I really don't understand what you want exactly. Can you update your ask giving more information?

Comment: Does the row in your database have an id?  I would probably inject the row id into the value of the radio button, then on the next page do a database query to retrieve that same data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use the MySQL primary key for each row, pass that info to the next page and have PHP perform a query for that item on the new page rather than explicitly passing content around from page to page.

That said, you can keep track of the order that you are echoing the keys in an array, then use that array to turn the row into an object:

```
var keys = ['sellername','itemname','maker','details','condition','price'];
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function(event) {
   if (this.checked) {
      var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
      var $cells = $tr.find('td');
      var obj = {};
      $.each($cells, function(index, cell) {
         obj[keys[index]] = cell.textContent;
      });
      console.log('row data', obj);
   }
});
```

Note this is untested, but just demonstrates how you can match up an array of key names to the index their data can be found in a table cell